# Is it possible to obtain user's facebook id and profile picture without asking him to log-in?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-7.1

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the Facebook user ID of a Windows Phone user without asking the user to log-in. Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, none of Facebook's APIs will give you information about the 'current' (/active) user unless they've authorised your application

Comment: i am agree with you that its not possible but why fdacebook said in his doc that you can get the information without access_token any idea?

Comment: @Abdullah If you have the user's facebook ID you can get some basic information which is publicly available.

Comment: yes you are again right but i think there is no way to get user id without authorization

Comment: Correct, you need them to allow access before you can see their user Id - once you have the user ID - some information is public and doesn't need an access token